# What is "dish" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a particular meaning of this word. Online I found these English definitions:

"Food that is prepared in a particular way."

"A particular variety or preparation of food: Sushi is a Japanese dish."

Answer (score 7):

I would use the word *plado*. As well as being a type of large plate to carry food, PIV has this definition:

> 3. Ĉiu el la diversaj mangaĵoj, kiuj konsistigas menuon: *en la restoracioj oni rajtis nur unupladan manĝon.*

Translation:

> 3. All of the diverse foods that make up a menu: *in restaurants one was only allowed a one-dish meal*

I think the example shows it being used in the way you intended. The two meanings match the English word which can also mean a type of plate used to carry the food.

Comment: I think *plado* is the best word if it is easy to guess that you are talking about food. Otherwise use *manĝaĵo*. (After all, a *yakimono-zara* is a *plado* of a sort, but not a *manĝaĵo*.)

Answer (score 2):

JC Wells gives *kuirado* as a translation of *cuisine*, which might be a better fit if you're talking about the origin of a dish. For example, *Suŝio estas ano de japana kuirado*.

Comment: Question: could you go one further and say _Suŝio estas japana kuiradano_?

Comment: I learned through lernu.net that "kuirado" means "cooking". The whole phrase was "Lia sxatokupo estas kuirado" or something similar.

Comment: What about "kuirajxo"? That would make a cousine a kuirajxaro